# Running Python script from shell invokes wrong interpreter

Tags: python, windows, virtualenv

Using Windows 7, I have three versions of Python installed.

- `C:\tools\python2\python.exe`
- `C:\tools\python3\python.exe`
- `C:\users\adsmith\.virtualenvs\flask_project\Scripts\python.exe`

Running `where python` inside my virtualenv confirms this.

```
C:\Users\adsmith\.virtualenvs\flask_project\Scripts\python.exe
C:\tools\python3\python.exe
C:\tools\python2\python.exe
```

And running `python` within the virtualenv invokes the first interpreter

```
(flask_project) C:\Users\adsmith\workspace\flask_project\flaskr>python
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 24 2015, 22:44:40) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'C:\\Users\\adsmith\\.virtualenvs\\flask_project\\Scripts\\python.exe'
```

However if I create a `.py` file inside the virtualenv and run it directly, it runs from the system Python 2 interpreter and I can't tell why. Running `python scriptname.py` works appropriately.

```
(flask_project) C:\Users\adsmith>echo import sys; print(sys.executable) > tmp.py

(flask_project) C:\Users\adsmith>tmp.py
C:\tools\python2\Python.exe

(flask_project) C:\Users\adsmith>python tmp.py
C:\Users\adsmith\.virtualenvs\flask_project\Scripts\python.exe
```

For reference:

```
(flask_project) C:\Users\adsmith>assoc .py
.py=Python.File

(flask_project) C:\Users\adsmith>ftype Python.File
Python.File="python" "%1" %*
```

Comment: Fix `Python.File` and `Python.NoConFile` to use the path to py.exe (and pyw.exe) as reported by `where py.exe`. Then if you want a Python script to depend on the environment's path to python.exe (such as from a virtual environment), use the following shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python`.

Comment: @eryksun Hmm that works perfectly, though I have no idea *why*. If you could write up an answer on it I'll accept and toss in some bounty for solving the problem. Specifically: why doesn't `"python" "%1" %*` work if `python tmp.py` works?

Comment: I'm surprised it works at all, unless you have a default path for `python` or `python.exe` configured. I can make it work like that. Use regedit to check for such a key under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths`. The way this works is cmd.exe calls `ShellExecuteEx` to run `tmp.py`, which gets the command line for `Python.File` and subsequently gets the real executable path for "python" from the `App Paths` key.

Comment: @eryksun both `C:\tools\python2` and `C:\tools\python3` are on my PATH, which is why I expect it to work. Shouldn't `"python" "%1" %*` just run the first `python` it finds on my PATH? I have no vested interest in how it works: just want to understand what's going on :)

Comment: At this stage, once `ShellExecuteEx` is looking up the filetype association in the registry, the final command line can be derived from various possible registry keys, but AFAIK it is not based on searching `PATH`. Try removing all references to Python directories from `PATH` such that `where python` doesn't find `python.exe`. Then run `start /b /w python`. Does this run `C:\tools\python2\python.exe`? If so, that's due to an `App Paths` key.